# Migration— declined - Cross-Validated is part of the standard migration path

Tags: support, migration

I haven't flagged many questions, but I recently realized most of the flags I've raised were denied. The most common reason was "*declined - Cross-Validated is part of the standard migration path.*" However, Cross-Validated isn't available when I go through the options.

Is this an option and I'm daft?

How do I educate myself so that I raise flags correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The address of Cross-Validated SE is stats.stackexchange.com

[image]

Comment: Wow. I didn't realize that stats and Cross Validated were the same. Sigh. Thank you so much...I guess I am daft!